# Can I pip install a cython module and make its pxds available for cimport?

Tags: python, pip, cython

I'm trying to `pip install` a Cython library (https://github.com/kmike/marisa-trie/tree/master/src, for example) and then subclass it in Cython by cimporting from its pxds. Is there any way to make the related pxds from the library available to me so I can cimport from them? I've checked a bunch of related info in Cython docs like [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html), but all of it deals with the case where pxd files are available in relative folders and not pip installed somewhere.

Comment: `marisa_trie` does not currently install the pxd files. The only file installed is the compiled Python module.

Comment: It makes no difference. I can get access to source and customize the install. The question isn't about marisa_trie, it's about this issue in general.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "package_data" setting and associated settings you can add to setup.py, e.g.

```
setup(...,
      packages=['helpers']
      package_dir={'helpers': 'src/helpers'},
      package_data={'helpers': ['*.pxd']},
)
```

Check out:
http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#search-paths-for-definition-files

and I've taken the example above from here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/fYaqdkSfCI0